# Rails - DB Relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have a Car and Driver dbs but for some records there is no driver for a car. How do I map the relation?

Here's the code I got and it causes an error of "NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass"

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_one :driver, :foreign_key  => :dr_code, :primary_key  => :ca_master_code
end

class Driver < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car, :foreign_key  => :dr_code, :primary_key  => :ca_master_code
end
```

Please advise.

Comment: Btw, is there any reason you're not following the Rails column-naming convention?

Comment: I'm working off of legacy db.

Answer (score 1):

It's assumed that `nil` in this case indicates that there's no driver there. This isn't a db design issue.

If a car without a driver is a valid case (as opposed to a mistake in the creation of the records), then just handle the `nil` case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was expecting Active Record to return those without a driver as nil but instead it throws an exception which I'm unable to rescue. Doesn't rails have a 'has_one_or_none' type of relation?

Comment: Well, you're calling `.each` on a `nil` object, which is always going to throw an exception. You don't need to rescue from that; simply check if it's `nil` before trying to call `each` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Rails is doing this perfectly fine. I'm assuming you're calling `each` on `car.driver`. Because the car does NOT have a driver, `car.driver` is `nil` and `nil.each` barfs.

Comment: Btw, why would you be calling `each` on a has_one relationship?

Comment: Each is being called I believe due to performing a 'find_all' with an :include in the query. Car.find_all_by_ca_active('Y', :include => [:driver]). Just executing that query in console gives back that error. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What's the output of `Car.find_all_by_ca_active('Y')` without the :include ?